# Existence of ER bridge among entangled pairs

Tags: quantum-entanglement

Recently I have read ER=EPR paper written by Leonard Susskind. It suggests  "where there is the entanglement, and there exist spacetime geometrical connection between such pairs". But how one can prove that, there exist a Planckian wormhole between the entangled pairs? Are such measurements possible in near future?

Comment: You should give more context. Does he tall of "a Planckian black hole" ? is it your interpretation?

Comment: Planckian Wormhole as he suggested

Comment: the paper is https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0533

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked through t[he paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0533), it is a proposal in order to reconcile general relativity and quantum mechanics on black holes, as far as I can see.

I can answer this question though :

> there exist a Planckian wormhole between the entangled pairs? Are such measurements possible in near future?

The answer is no, because the Planckian scale is the scale where the standard model of particle physics no longer works, and experiments in the lab are not possible at those dimensions :

> [The term Planck scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units) refers to the magnitudes of space, time, energy and other units, below which (or beyond which) the predictions of the Standard Model, quantum field theory and general relativity are no longer reconcilable, and quantum effects of gravity are expected to dominate. This region may be characterized by energies around $1.22×10^{19}$ GeV (the Planck energy), time intervals around $5.39×10^{−44}$ s (the Planck time) and lengths around $1.62×10^{−35}$ m (the Planck length). At the Planck scale, current models are not expected to be a useful guide to the cosmos, and physicists have no scientific model to suggest how the physical universe behaves.

In the colliders the energy possible is very much smaller, and will never reach the order of magnitude $1.22×10^{19}$ GeV . It would have to be detailed models that would give predictions possible to observe in the CMB or during black hole merging, and from the paper it is clear that there is no such detailed calculation up to now, just thought experiments.